# How do we enable Foundation models in Einstein Studio?

Tags: einstein, datacloud

I'm investigating the Bring Your Own Model feature of Salesforce Einstein. I can't seem to find where to register our model.

I found a [Salesforce Help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_ai_foundation_models_create.htm&type=5) which says to go to 'Foundation Models' in Einstein Studio. Other pages I found show 'Foundation Models' as a tab in Einstein Studio. My Studio doesn't have such an option/tab.

I also found a [screenshot](https://www.salesforceben.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/image2-4-1024x680.png) from a Salesforce Ben article showing the Model Builder with an option for 'Connect a model on another platform'. My Model Builder has the first three options, but does not have that one.

Is there an option I need to enable to do this? I can't seem to find one in either the Data Cloud or the Einstein sections of Salesforce Setup.

Comment: Just in case someone views this in the future, the problem was that even though the Foundation models were part of the Spring'24 release, they weren't actually available until the end of February. Once February 29th rolled around, the tab showed up in Einstein Studio.